# I can't insert quote, in the example section in compodoc

Tags: angular, compodoc

i'm documenting my project with 'compodoc' and i like this tool but i get a error visual when i try insert a quote.

i have this comment

```
/**
   * crea un arreglo de tamaño n
   *
   * @example
   * *ngFor="let item of 2 | numberToArray"
   *
   * @param length tamaño del nuevo arreglo
   *
   * @returns un arreglo de tamaño n
   */
```

i expect this

```
example:
1| *ngFor="let item of 2 | numberToArray"
```

but the actual output is

```
example:
1| *ngFor=&quot;let item of 2 | numberToArray&quot;
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused since your [expected output is the same as the actual output](https://www.diffchecker.com/8Ag3tTNC) in your example. Try escaping the quotation marks `\"Foo bar\"`

Comment: yes, & quot; and "they are the same, but they are not the same visually

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `@example` jsdoc tag and enclose the code in ```ts.
See more about workaround https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/304

From

```
/**
 * crea un arreglo de tamaño n
 *
 * @example
 * *ngFor="let item of 2 | numberToArray"
 */
```

To

````
/**
 * crea un arreglo de tamaño n
 *
 * ```ts
 * *ngFor="let item of 2 | numberToArray"
 * ```
 */
````